# Import "multipledispatch" could not be resolved - Pylance

Tags: python, vscode

He instalado el módulo multipledispatch, todo bien, el archivo funciona con el módulo como debería, no hay errores en la consola, pero VS Code subraya el `multipledispatch` de `from multipledispatch import dispatch` de amarillo (amarillo en la skin por defecto), como si no supiera donde está.

Esto me pasa en un virtual environment, tal vez eso tenga algo que ver.

¿Alguien sabe como desactivar Pylance SOLO para ese import o hacer que reconozca el virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

Ya tengo la respuesta! En mi caso, la solución fue cambiar de interpretador, antes estaba en `Python 3.10.0`, y al cambiar a 3.8.10 la línea amarilla desapareció y ya Pylance no me da ningún error.

Esto está en la barra de abajo, donde aparece el lenguaje que usas, algunos iconos de extensiones como git, el UTF-8... etc

A la izquierda, donde pone `Python X.X.X` puedes dar click y desplegará la lista de interpretadores.

Le dí al recomendado, en mi caso poniendo `3.8.10 64-bit ('venv': venv)` (No se si siempre es igual) y se solucionó todo.

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.